# event.stopPropogation() not working in IPAD/Tablet

Tags: javascript, frontend, coveo

I am using coveo Framework and i used facets inside a dropdown button i wrote a window.onclick function so that when clicked outside dropdown button the dropdown should be closed.
everything seems to be working fine but when i clicked facets checkbox the dropdown was closing and when i talked to coveo team they said the query was triggered when coveo checkbox was clicked thats the reason the dropdown was closing when clicked.
To fix this i used event.stopPropogation and that was working fine in desktop mode but when it comes to IPAD Mode this is not working any help
Here is my code

```
// Prevent event bubble up to window.
document.getElementById('dropdown').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  
});

function close() {
  document.getElementById('dropdown').classList.remove('show');
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|Blackberry/i)) {
    if ((!event.target.matches('.dropdown-backdrop')) && event.target.closest('#dropdown') === null) {
      close();
  }

 }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried event.preventDefault(); ?

I'm taking a wild guess that because the checkbox is a native element, that might be the reason why the event passes through.

Comment: yeah even i tried this but its not working

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is on a touch screen device, you actually get [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) possibly in addition to [mouse events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events#Mouse_events).  I suspect if you attached another listener to `touchstart` that does the same thing as `click` you will see the same results on the tablet.

In theory you should see no click events on a tablet (a user cannot click without a mouse) but in practice the browser emulates click events.  However, when those events are generated [*the browser may fire both touch events and mouse events in response to the same user input*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Supporting_both_TouchEvent_and_MouseEvent).  If both events are fired you're successfully stopping the click event from propagating but not the touch event.

*Update*

You haven't given enough detail to fully give an example, but the change happens in the listeners you attach to your `dropdown` element.

```
// Note instead of using the same anonymous function twice,
//   I've defined a function to stop propigation
function stopProp(e) {e.stopImmediatePropagation();}
document.getElementById('dropdown').addEventListener('click',stopProp);
document.getElementById('dropdown').addEventListener('touchstart',stopProp);
```

Comment: Thank you any Example you can provide ?

Comment: Thank you for the Update this was working fine i feel this function is not calling in tablet i feel its not taking window.onclick so is there any chance that i can write ontouchstart which can work for both desktop and tablet  here is my code.                    
   window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|webOS|iPhone|Blackberry/i)) {
    if ((!e.target.matches('.dropdown-backdrop')) && e.target.closest('#dropdown') === null)  {
      console.log("closingthefilter")
      closeFilter();
  }

 }
};

Comment: Sorry - I don't quite understand your question.  If you're asking can you just use one of touch or click - the answer is, sadly, no.  A machine without a touch interface won't report touch events, and a machine without a mouse may not report click events.  Note you cannot browser-agent sniff to solve this, since you can have eg touch-screen PCs which will give touch events for screen interaction, and click events for mouse interaction.

Comment: No i was just asking as i am getting the issue only in Ipad so can i write any touchstart function for Ipad because for me in desktop its working perfectly fine with the above code